# AgularJS: How to close active $modal on session timeout

Tags: angularjs, session-timeout, angularjs-routing, bootstrap-modal

I'm developing a SPA, on session timeout i will redirect the user to login page. Here is my implementation

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$location', function ($rootScope, $state, $location) {

    $rootScope.$watch(function detectIdle() {

    var now = new Date();

     if (now - lastDigestRun > 20 * 60 * 1000) {

        $location.path('/login');

        setTimeout(function () {
          alert("Your session has expired. Please log in again");
        }, 1000); 
     }
   });

}])
```

Problem: If application timeouts when some $modal is open, page redirect to login page but $modal will not close.

please help me to solve the problem

Thanks

**Update: Sorry for answering my own question, Working Solution given below:**

```
 .run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$location', function ($rootScope, $state, $location) {

    var isSessionTimeout = false; 

    $rootScope.$watch(function detectIdle() {

    var now = new Date();

     if (now - lastDigestRun > 20 * 60 * 1000) {

        isSessionTimeout = true;
        $location.path('/login');

        setTimeout(function () {
          alert("Your session has expired. Please log in again");
        }, 1000); 
     }
   });

  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function () {
    if (isSessionTimedOut) {
        $modalStack.dismissAll();
    }             
 });

}])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the session expired you redirect user to login with

```
 $location.path('/login');
```

So in order to close all open modals in one place after redirect you can subscribe on the 
$`routeChangeSuccess` event of $`rootScope` and use `$modalStack.dismissAll();`

```
 app.run(['$rootScope', '$modalStack', function ($rootScope, $modalStack) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function () {
        $modalStack.dismissAll();
    });
 }]);
```

Comment: Thanks Alex and Mart, both of your solution worked for me. @Alex instead of $routeChangeSuccess i used $stateChangeSuccess then only it worked.

Comment: This is because you use AngularUI Router for routing instead of default ngRoute  module in Angular.

Comment: what is `$modalStack` here ?

Answer (score 1):

You can notify that the session ended with:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('sessionEnd');
```

And in the controller of all your modals:

```
$scope.$on('sessionEnd', function() {
    $modalInstance.dismiss();
});
```

Comment: Thanks mart nice suggestion. I'm very new to AngularJS now i understood how $broadcast will work